# Can I debug an assembly which is loaded with reflection in Vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, reflection, assemblies

I have two assemblies : A.dll which has a reference to B.dll.
And B.dll uses reflection to call some methods from A.dll.

My question is that any breakpoints I use on B.dll when debugging A.dll will be hit?

Comment: Did you try it? Why not?

Comment: I tried it,but the behaviour is very strange. Only if I hit step into it will go into the code from reflected assembly. The breakpoint are not considered.

Comment: See my answer below. Generally it should work. If it doesn't in your concrete scenario, please provide more info, for example the calling code and the code with the breakpoint

Comment: i mixed up the assemblies,sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the debugger was able to find a matching pdb file the breakpoints are being hit.
BTW: In the scenario you described A.dll is not loaded via reflection. You merely use reflection to call a method in the already loaded A.dll.